# Issue with the combination of ssh, bash --login and exec

Tags: ssh, bash, exec

Here are few situations I'm in.
`foo` is the ssh server to which password less login is set up.

```
$ ssh foo
$ bash --login -c 'exec $0 "$@"' ls -lrt
```

It's working as expected.

```
ssh foo bash --login -c ls -lrt
```

This is not working as expected. Only `ls` is working ignoring the `-lrt` parameter.

And my requirement is to run the 1st example with ssh like

```
ssh foo bash --login -c 'exec $0 "$@"' ls -lrt
```

I know I've problems from the 2nd example itself. But I was just trying something to make it work and to find where the problem is. The 3rd example is not showing any error/output at all.

How do I proceed to achieve the 3rd example?

Comment: Why the complication of `ssh foo bash --login -c ls -lrt` over a simpler `ssh foo 'ls -lrt'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `ssh foo bash --login -c '"exec \$0 \$@"' ls -lrt`.

To find out what actually happens, `strace` is your friend.

`ssh foo strace -vff -e execve bash --login -c 'exec $0 "$@"' ls -lrt` gives me something like:

`execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "--login", "-c", "exec", "zsh", "ls", "-lrt"], [LANG=…]`

My shell is zsh, which should give you a hint to what's happening here: That `$0` is interpreted by the shell spawned to parse the command line sent over the SSH command.  If we just escape the `$0` and `"$@"` parts like: `ssh foo  strace -vff -e execve bash --login -c 'exec \$0 "\$@"' ls -lrt` we get:

`execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "--login", "-c", "exec", "$0", "$@", "ls", "-lrt"], ["LANG=..`. As you can see here, bash is called with the arguments `--login`, `-c`, `exec`, `$0` and so on. This doesn't get us all the way to where we want to be, since it's now effectively just calling `exec` by itself.  To work around this, we need to quote what comes after the `-c` argument so it's not unpacked too early, like `ssh foo strace -vff -e execve bash --login -c '"exec \$0 \$@"' ls -lrt`:

`execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "--login", "-c", "exec $0 $@", "ls", "-lrt"], ["LANG=…`

This is accepted by bash, since it allows you to use `$@`, but if you're writing proper POSIX sh, you should use `"$@"`, in which case the right answer is `ssh foo strace -vff -e execve bash --login -c '"exec \$0 \"\$@\""' ls -lrt`:

`execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "--login", "-c", "exec $0 \"$@\"", "ls", "-lrt"], ["LANG=…`

I assume you're using `ls -lrt` as a proxy for some other more complex command that actually needs `bash --login` and such, else just do what  suggested in the first comment and use `ssh foo 'ls -lrt'` instead.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. That's just a proxy. The command I'm using is to use a different library and the command itself is 2-3 lines long. Thanks for the `strace` information. I was searching for something like that but couldn't word a proper search string in google.

Answer (score 1):

The `ssh` accepts exactly one argument as a command, therefore it should be in the quotes or apostrophes. The same applies for the `bash -c` argument -- it is just a single argument that is accepted. The others are passed to the `bash` instead of `ls`. The following example works just fine:

```
ssh foo 'bash --login -c "ls -lrt"'
```